# cuDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED when trying to run a tutorial CNN with tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, nvidia

I am trying to run a simple python script with a convolutional neural network (CNN). Every time I run the script I come across the following error message

```
2021-03-10 19:47:03.832061: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:328] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CNN_trial.py", line 17, in <module>
    outputs = tf.nn.conv2d(images,filters,strides = 1,padding = "SAME")
  File "D:\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 2158, in conv2d_v2
    return conv2d(input,  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "D:\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 2264, in conv2d
    return gen_nn_ops.conv2d(
  File "D:\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py", line 942, in conv2d
    return conv2d_eager_fallback(
  File "D:\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py", line 1031, in conv2d_eager_fallback
    _result = _execute.execute(b"Conv2D", 1, inputs=_inputs_flat, attrs=_attrs,
  File "D:\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above. [Op:Conv2D]
```

My system is as follows
Windows 10

AMD Ryzen 7 3700x

16GB RAM

Nvidia RTX 2060

Python 3.8.5

Tensorflow 2.4.1

my full code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

china = load_sample_image("china.jpg")/255
flower = load_sample_image("flower.jpg")/255
images = np.array([china,flower])
batch_size, height,width,channels = images.shape
filters = np.zeros(shape=(7,7,channels,2),dtype=np.float32)
filters[:,3,:,0] = 1
filters[3,:,:,1] = 1
outputs = tf.nn.conv2d(images,filters,strides = 1,padding = "SAME")
plt.imshow(outputs[0,:,:,1],cmap = "gray")
plt.show()
```

Comment: You might have another instance of the code still running. So the original instance is still using the GPU which you must terminate to do what you want to do

Comment: So should I close all other applications that could be running the code? I am using VS code and I didn't have another IDE open running any code.

Comment: @BrainE There could be multiple terminals open in one VS code window

Comment: I closed all other VS code windows except the one I am using and still get the same error

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I need to set the memory growth. By adding the following two lines to the beginning of the script. I got it to at least run.

```
devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(devices[0],True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have nvidia-cuda-cu11==8.6.0.56

```
import tensorflow as tf
num_gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(num_gpus[0],True)
```